# Update query with ISNULL in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

DateTime Should update if the data is passed else update it with original value which is already saved. This update does not works

```
DECLARE @FolderStatusDate DATETIME = NULL

SET @FolderStatusDate = '2012-07-04 14:09:04.043'

UPDATE CM.PfmFolder     
  SET   
      FolderStatusDate = ISNULL(@FolderStatusDate, FolderStatusDate)
      WHERE Id = @Id
```

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server. AFAIK, `ifnull` is MySql and is not available in SQL Server

Comment: The script in the question will not work because `@id` is neither declared nor set, but the query seems correct. What "does not works" mean? You get an error, the data is not updated when it should, or the opposite, or what else?

Comment: Side note: It's a good habit to get into to write "literal" dates with `T` as the separator rather the space, e.g. `'2012-07-04T14:09:04.043'` - `'2012-07-04 14:09:04.043'` can be interpreted (under weird circumstances) as either `yyyy-mm-dd...` or `yyyy-dd-mm...`

Comment: To expand on @Damien's point, there's an alternative way to represent a timestamp unambiguously – just omit the hyphens (`-`) in the date part: `20120704 14:09:04.043`. It is true that either method makes the original form less readable, but I believe consistency is more important and at least you've got more than one unambiguous format to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you move the check for `NULL` to the `WHERE` clause?

```
DECLARE @FolderStatusDate DATETIME = NULL

SET @FolderStatusDate = '2012-07-04 14:09:04.043'

UPDATE CM.PfmFolder     
  SET   
      FolderStatusDate = @FolderStatusDate
      WHERE Id = @Id  
      AND @FolderStatusDate IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `IS NULL` check be on @FolderStatusDate? (and be `IS NOT NULL`)

Comment: Your query is identical to the OP's in terms of the final data state. The only difference is that your query would skip updating any rows if `@FolderStatusDate` was NULL instead of overwriting the column with same values. Seems a good measure in terms of performance optimisation but how does it solve the problem at hand (which is not even clear at this point)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way

```
DECLARE @FolderStatusDate DATETIME = NULL

SET @FolderStatusDate = '2012-07-04 14:09:04.043'

UPDATE CM.PfmFolder     
SET   
  FolderStatusDate = case when ISNULL(@FolderStatusDate, '') = '' 
                           then FolderStatusDate else @FolderStatusDate end
  WHERE Id = @Id
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight edit on **Hitesh Salian's** answer

```
 DECLARE @FolderStatusDate DATETIME = NULL

 SET @FolderStatusDate = '2012-07-04 14:09:04.043'

 UPDATE CM.PfmFolder     
 SET   
 FolderStatusDate = case @FolderStatusDate is Null
                       then FolderStatusDate else @FolderStatusDate end
 WHERE Id = @Id
```